# Display affected by drop down using CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a nav bar configured to hide drop down elements (using `display:none`) until hovered over when it will show as a drop down (using `display:block` at `a:hover`).  It all works great except the "divs" below it are pushed down when drop down displays.  How can I get the "divs" to remain in place regardless of the display of the drop down items?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make your menu `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` then you need to give your top-most element a `margin-top` of whatever the height of your nav is.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you

```
<h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Deep menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deep menu2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub deep menu1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub deep menu2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub deep menu3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deep menu3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Category1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
.nav {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.nav ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: block;
}
.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav li:hover ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
.nav li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.nav li ul li:hover ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
.nav li ul li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vca3sbs/)

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` elements which contain the dropdown parts have to have `position: absolute`. That way they don't occupy any space in the surrounding containers. Tune their position n relation to their parent elements with the `top` and `left` (or right) settings.

The parent elements of those DIVs need to have `position: relative` to enable the absolute positioning of their children elements.

By the way, `position: fixed` wouldn't work that well, since this positions an element absolutely to the window, which in most cases you don't want (exception: if you have a fixed navbar).