# Bootstrap 3: Navbar Tabs Equal to Page Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create spaced tabs. I want about 6-8 of them running across the width of the screen, each with equal distance apart from each other. I also need them to have dropdown ability on hover.

Initially I went with Bootstrap 3 for quick and fast tabs. However, I can't seem to get them to space equally across the width of the page.

Alternatively, I found this awesome [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/zfSt4/) of code which is pure css. However, I'm far from a css wizard and making a pure dropdown like the tabs would take me a long time.

Anyone know a solution to the bootstrap 3 problem of spacing or know where I can get a pure css dropdown solution? Bootstrap 3 code below, pure css in jsfiddle link

Thanks!

Code:

```
<ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
  <li class='dropdown'>
    <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Test 1</a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li><a href='#'>test 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='dropdown'>
    <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Test 2</a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li><a href='#'>test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='dropdown'>
    <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Test 3</a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li><a href='#'>test 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [pure css dropdown menu](http://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/4vca3sbs/1/)  and link to [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929863/display-affected-by-drop-down-using-css/27930703#27930703)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enclose your code inside a div with `container-fluid` class. It will help you to utilize entire width of apge.

```css
ul.nav-tabs > li {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
    <li class='dropdown'>
      <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Test 1</a>
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href='#'>test 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='dropdown'>
      <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Test 2</a>
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href='#'>test 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='dropdown'>
      <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Test 3</a>
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href='#'>test 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The tabs are all to the left side of the screen. I need them equally spaced out and stretch the entire width of the page.

Comment: @user2465134 I have added a little css in my code to serve your purpse. But in this approach, you will have set width of tab to (100 / no_of_tabs) %;

Comment: Yeah that's not a bad idea. I'll run with that.